# reference error not defined

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
create2.innerHTML =  create2.innerHTML+  " <img onclick = 'a()'  src =' "+ messages[msg].thumb + "'  height='90' width='142'> </a>  ";
    function a (){

    }
```

> So I am trying to include an onlick event on image tag so that when it is click a function is called. However, I am getting the following error :

Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined onclick 
Can somebody please explain why this is happening?

Comment: What does the rest of the code look like? Is the function "a" inside a function?

Comment: yes the function a is inside another function

Comment: Well there is your problem. The onclick is looking for it in global scope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why using inline events is a bad idea. Your scope is window, so it looks for the click in the window. When the function is inside another, you have no access to it.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = messages[msg].thumb;
img.style.height = "90px";
img.style.width = "142px";
img.onclick = a;   //would be better to use addEventListener()
create2.appendChild(img);
```